# Minimum to Maximum spanning trees?

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, graph-theory, minimum-spanning-tree

I have seen where one can modify classic Mininum spanning tree algorithms to find the Maximum spanning tree instead.

Can an algorithm such as Kruskal's be modified to return a spanning tree that is strictly more costly than an MST, but is the next cheapest. So you can switch one of the edges in this spanning tree, you end up with an MST and vice versa.

I would assume then, that there is a range of spanning trees in terms of their overall cost.

My question is simply how can I find the next cheapest spanning tree, given a graph with an MST.

Comment: Call an edge *safe* if it belongs to some MST. The cheapest spanning tree that's not minimum includes exactly one unsafe edge.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22109647/faster-second-best-mst-algorithm and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692678/second-min-cost-spanning-tree

Comment: crossposted with TCS http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/27062/minimum-to-maximum-spanning-trees